# Typscript shows never when I exclude a type

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, types

I am trying to restrict a type in a type object by excluding one of its type, but it shows never.

I tried this in the TS Playground.

```
type T1 = Exclude<"a" | "b" | "c", "a" | "b">;
//    ^? type T1 = "c"
type T2 = Exclude<string | number | (() => void), Function>;
//    ^? type T2 = string | number

type TA = { a: string, b: number, c: T1[] | T2[] }

type T3 = Omit<TA, 'c'> & Record<keyof Pick<TA, 'c'>, Exclude<TA['c'], T1[]>>;
//    ^? type T3 = Omit<TA, "c"> & Record<"c", T2[]>

const myObj: T3 = {
    a :'',
    b: 0,
    c: ["c"]
}
```

The above scenario works fine. But when I change the `Exclude` part to `Exclude<TA['c'], T2[]>`

It shows never for c as shown below.

```
type T3 = Omit<TA, 'c'> & Record<keyof Pick<TA, 'c'>, Exclude<TA['c'], T2[]>>;
//    ^? type T3 = Omit<TA, "c"> & Record<"c", never>
```

Any Suggestions?

Here is the TS Playground link for reference -> https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFAogDwMYBsCuATCAHgCIBDYqAHymICMLriNiAaG8qm+gPgG4AoAPSCooqAD0A-P1CRYAJiSpMuAoQDOwAE4BLAHYBzTnpwBbWhC2cAFNYCUSblABuAex147bAGI49GYB1XPT4hETEpfhlwaBgAQSUAbyhSAC4oTV1DNlp0k3NLNgx0+ABtAF1OGHkKqABfKNlYgGYlAHlTHWBCeLYAcgw+pwAyKAAlCAxXLTxCAGsIEFcAMygABR0MOZ64-sHuNnRsfCJ40oG+8rZqiu5Q4TEJaX4pvU0oUxA22gArEtbkIl+I9SFBUn0+ixgWJclAAAxQx7FKClJjEcr8OpAA

Comment: It's a bit of a side point, but assuming `TA` has a key `"c"` (which it does), isn't `keyof Pick<TA, 'c'>` just....`"c"`?

Comment: Do you mean the different quotes are causing it? I tried it just now. But it didn't make any difference. It still shows never.

Comment: No, `'c'` and `"c"` are identical. I mean that `Pick<TA, "c">` creates an object type like `{c: T1[] | T2[]; }` and then `keyof` extracts the only key from that, which is `"c"`. So there's no point to `keyof Pick<TA, "c">`; just use `"c"`. (Again: **Assuming** there's  a `"c"` key in `TA`, which there is.)

Comment: Re your actual problem, here's a much more minimal example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDOwBOBLAdgcygHykwFcBbAIwlQG4AoAejqiYD0B+Gm0SKAQQSgBEAYwEBtALr5YE2gyZQ2HLtAAa-AKIAPIQBsiAEwgAeHgBpp4gHyzGLdkA And I have no idea why that happens! :-)

Comment: I got it. But the reason I thought of using `keyof` is to make sure that I have one place where I define the object and its properties. If I use, for example, c directly, then when I change the property name to d in future, it will still add c to the object. But when I use `keyof`,  it will show me a TS error *Type '"d"' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof TA'*

Comment: But yes, as you have shared a minimal example, still it shows never :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected as in the end `Exclude<TA['c'], T2[]>` comes down to `Exclude<T1[] | T2[], T2[]>`.

`T2[]` is being excluded from `T1[] | T2[]` so you end up with `Exclude<T1[], T2[]>`

`T1[]` is `"c"[]` and `T2[]` is the set of `(string|number)[]` which covers `"c"[]` so everything is getting excluded and you end up with `never`

`"c"[]` is assignable to `(string|number)[]`
so
`Exclude<"c"[], (string|number)[]>` is never

Comment: ***Doh!*** Of course. Well-spotted. I completely missed the type overlap.

Comment: Woah, that's right. Great. Any suggestion on how I can write it in a different manner to achieve the requirement?

Comment: What is the requirement ?

Comment: Sorry but couldn't get the original requirement clearly from the question. "trying to restrict a type in a type object by excluding one of its type" if this then you are excluding not one but all the types from the original type

Comment: No problem, I found a way to do it. This will give the same result without `never`, since I am assigning the value directly instead of `Exclude` -> `type T3 = Omit<TA, 'c'> & Record<keyof Pick<TA, 'c'>, T1[]>;`